# java.io.EOFException when using sockets with blockchain in java

Tags: java, sockets, blockchain

i have to do a practice in my uni, it must create a blockchain using sockets and serialization in a "simple way". But when exiting the loop (typing "NO") It creates a EOF exception that i cannot solve, while closing the socket(s.close()). i would appreciate some help, i am not vry good at java. here are my classes.

Client

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client implements Runnable{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     (new Thread(new Client())).start();


}
public static MedicalReport createReport(){

    return new MedicalReport(10,"pepe","id","record");

}
@Override
public void run() {
//  int port = 12345;       
      //  String computer = "localhost";
        try{
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 12348);
            ObjectOutputStream p = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
           /* PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            print.println("ready");
            print.flush();*/

          //manda informe al servidor serializado y espera respuesta
            boolean stop = false;
            while(!stop){
                try{
                MedicalReport report = createReport();
                p.writeObject(report);
                p.flush();
                p.reset();

                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Yes or No");
                Scanner in1 = new Scanner (System.in);
                String answer="";
                if(in1.hasNextLine())
                    answer = in1.nextLine();

                if(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                            System.out.println(report);
                    stop = true;


                    }   
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

            }

            try{
                    s.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

          }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
  }


}

}
```

SERVER

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Server {


public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<Block> blockChain = new ArrayList<>();
     try{
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12348);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

         /*   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            String text = scanner.nextLine();*/


            int i = 0;
            int previousHash = 0;
            while (i != 20){
                MedicalReport rp = (MedicalReport)in.readObject();
                Block block = new Block(rp,previousHash);
                blockChain.add(block);
                    System.out.println("Block " + blockChain.size() + " added to blockchain");
                System.out.println(blockChain.get(i));
                previousHash = block.getBlockHash();
                    System.out.println(blockChain);

                i++;
            }


            try{

                ss.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }


          }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

It looks like the error is while closing the socket, any idea?

**EDIT** REST OF THE CODE

MEDICAL REPORT

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class MedicalReport implements Serializable {

private int age;
private String name;
private String id;
private String record;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MedicalReport(){super();}
public MedicalReport(int age, String name, String id, String record) {
    super();
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.record = record;
}

public String getRecord(){
    return this.record;
}
public String toString(){
    return this.name + ". \n" + this.age + ". \n" + this.id + ". \n" + this.record;
}


}
```

BLOCK

```
public class Block {

private int blockHash;
private int previousHash;
private MedicalReport report;

//Block Constructor.
public Block(MedicalReport report,int previousHash ) {
    this.previousHash = previousHash;
    this.report = report;
    this.blockHash = report.hashCode();
}

public int getPreviousHash() {
    return previousHash;
}

public MedicalReport getReport() {
    return report;
}

public int getBlockHash() {
    return blockHash;
}
}
```

**EDIT 2**
FIRST QUESTION SOLVED. Now i get this error when exiting the loop:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Comment: EOFException indicates that the end of the file or memory stream was reached. Can you upload remaining code.

Comment: sure, but, there is not much more, only a class with the report and a class that creates the block with the hash and so. I dont think they are important for this code, as i said it is supossed to be "easy". I think the problem here is when closing the sockets, but i don't know ho it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT:** As EJP said `EOFException` is normal and you can control the flow of your code with it but if you still want to know how to do in the way you asked here it is. REMEMBER THIS IS JUST FULFILL YOUR QUESTION AND NOT ADVISED TO DO SO.

**On Server Class**

Replace

```
MedicalReport rp = (MedicalReport)in.readObject();
```

With

```
MedicalReport rp;
if((rp = (MedicalReport)in.readObject())==null) break;
```

**On Client Class**

ADD

```
p.writeObject(null);
```

Just above the `s.close();`  statement

> **You must know that when a peer close the connection normally then**

`read() returns -1`,

`readLine() returns null`,

`readXXX() throws EOFException` for any other `XXX`

And `A write will throw an IOException`

Comment: thank you very much, but now, when the while is over, it appears this error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Comment: while (i != 20) cases that problem

Comment: you can replace your while loop with while (s.isConnected()) and problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

`readObject()` throws `EOFEzception` when the peer has closed the connection. This is normal. Catch it and stop reading. There is no problem here to solve.